# Как изменить имя файла при загрузке на сервер

Tags: php

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('mp3', 'mp4', 'ogg', 'wav');
$BN = (isset($_POST['BN']) ? $_POST['BN'] : null);
$AN = (isset($_POST['AN']) ? $_POST['AN'] : null);

$music_path = "../../bands/".$BN."/music/".$AN;

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $music_path.'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}
else {
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}

?>
```

На входе имеем: *Bigg Mouth – American Girl.mp3*

На выходе: *Bigg Mouth вЂ“ American Girl.mp3*

Должно быть: *American Girl.mp3*

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Храните имена файлов в базе данных
2. Для хранения на диске используйте уникальное имя файла и то же храните его в БД. Например [md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) + соль

Иначе:

1. Что будет если к вам загрузят еще один раз `Bigg Mouth – American Girl.mp3`?
2. Что будет если к вам загрузят например с кириллицей в названии?
3. Как вы будете отдавать на скачку файлы? URL не поддерживает пробелы.

А для вашей конкретной проблемы в обработке названия песни как таковой могу предложить [делить строку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php) через разделитель и брать последнюю часть, например

```
// $realFileName Bigg Mouth – American Girl.mp3
$realFileName = $_FILES['upl']['name']; // имя файла
$split = preg_split("/[-|–|—|:|\/]/iu", $realFileName); // делим через возможные делители
$fileName = trim(end($split)); // нам нужна последняя часть имени файла
// $fileName будет равен American Girl.mp3
```

### UPD

Примерная реализация вашего варианта:

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('mp3', 'mp4', 'ogg', 'wav');
$bandName = (isset($_POST['BN']) ? $_POST['BN'] : null);
$artistName = (isset($_POST['AN']) ? $_POST['AN'] : null);

$music_path = __DIR__ . "/../../bands/".$bandName."/music/".$artistName;

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $reaFilelName = $_FILES['upl']['name'];
    $fileName = $music_path . '/' . md5($reaFilelName . time());

    $isAllow = in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed);
    if($isAllow && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $fileName)){
        // сохраняем в БД $reaFilelName для показа имени файла клиенту
        // сохраняем в БД $fileName для отдачи этого файла через php
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;

?>
```

Comment: можете помочь с реализацией, хоть примерно?

Comment: @zakihatfild обновил ответ